# How to add more than initial duration using SimpleTimer widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, flutter-packages, pub.dev

I created a SimpleTimer Widget using this package : https://pub.dev/packages/simple_timer

It's says on the doc that with the "add" method it allow to go over the initial duration. So here i set my initial duration at 20 sec and every time I get a correct answer I add 5 sec but I still can't get over the 20 sec that I set up..

Here is my Simple Timer code :

```
SimpleTimer(
                      timerStyle: TimerStyle.expanding_sector,
                      backgroundColor: splashBackground,
                      progressIndicatorColor: backgroundHighlight,
                      controller: _timerController,
                      duration: startingTime,
                      onEnd: () {
                        setState(() {
                          textField = false;
                        });
                        //go to results page?
                      },
                    ),
```

And here is the part where I use the "add" method :

```
 _timerController.add(
                      bonus,
                      start: true,
                    );
```

Comment: To better understand your question. After you've added the first 20 secs to the timer controller, you add 5 seconds and this 5 secs doesn't add. The timer is permanently stuck to 20 sec loop. 
A possible work around is,  I imagine you initialise the _timerController with TimerController() class, you could overwrite the _timerController with a new TimerController() and use the .add method.

Comment: It does add the 5 seconds but if I am at 17 sec it only goes back to 20 sec instead of adding the 5 sec and going to 22 sec..
The 20 sec is the startingTime and the 5 sec is the bonus

Comment: From my understanding of the package, it's a countdown timer. so once you initialise it with a duration. it doesn't go beyond that duration. a quick solution for  you would be to get the current seconds left, add the new seconds to it and recreate the timer with the new duration.

Comment: Ok I'll look into it.. Any idea how to get the duration left?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the add function implemented correctly.

```
_timerController.add(Duration(seconds: 5));
```

this would be called from whatever function determines the answer is correct.

Comment: Already doing it with the bonus variable.. It still doesn't go above the startingTime..

Comment: Make sure bonus is a duration object.